# Query with object parameter

Tags: android, android-room

How to do a room query using a instance of a class as a data source:
The following example will make my question clear:

```
@Query("UPDATE CATEGORIES SET Name = :item.Name, Active = :item.Active " +
"WHERE CategoryID = :item.CategoryID")
fun updateCategory(item: EntityCategory)
```

I tried

```
@Update
fun updateCategory(item: EntityCategory)
```

But that would delete all refrencing data

My Entity class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "CATEGORIES")
data class EntityCategory(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
        var CategoryID: Long,
        var Name: String,
        var Active: Boolean) {
    constructor(item: DMCategory) : this(item.CategoryID, item.Name, item.Active)
}
```

I cant have my Primary key auto generated.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
```